# setContextClassLoader implications

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Similar to this question: [setContextClassLoader implications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330885/setcontextclassloader-implications), I am trying to clean up warnings about memory leaks. Specifically, I have a servlet with code as follows:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, 
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
    class BasicThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            // Do a finite amount of stuff here
        }
    }
    Thread thread = new BasicThread();
    //thread.setContextClassLoader(null);
    thread.start();
}
```

This article: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection#cclThreadSpawnedByWebApp, indicates that if I uncomment the setContextClassLoader line, then the error messages will go away.

But my question is: is there a memory leak? If so, I don't want to just make the warnings go away, I want to fix the leak. How do I do so?

Thanks.

(also, if I change the line "// Do a finite amount of stuff here" to "// Do an *infinite* amount of stuff here (ie, loop forever)", then what is the proper way of ensuring no memory leaks in this scenario?)

Comment: humbling suggesting you looking at the link, and some discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179733/threadfactory-usage-in-java/4730500#4730500. Either way starting threads this way is just bogus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a real issue if the following are true.  1.  The thread never stops, if the thread never stops there is no GC root and the `ClassLoader` can never be garbage collected.  2.  Your application is doing hot deployments then you should definitely take this into account.

The underlying issue is, when you want to un-deploy and re-deploy, the application server will want to GC the WAR's classloader.  If the WAR has created a Thread strongly referencing the WAR's classloader and the Thread has not completed the classlodaer can never get garbage collected and eventually you will see a Out of memory: Permagen.

If you restart your server (and JVM) for each deployment the issue wouldn't manifest.

I read through the article you posted and they describe exactly what I suggested

> SEVERE: A web application appears to
>   have started a thread named
>   [leakingThread] but has failed to stop
>   it. This is very likely to create a
>   memory leak.

For more of a point of reference, I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742050/classloader-leak-are-they-worth-solving) regarding classloader leaks.

Comment: unfortunately, there is more to that... like starting Other threads (esp. w/ the stupid ThreadFactory of some ExecutorService).

Comment: Thanks. Your links are helpful and I will do further reading. 1. The thread does stop. 2. We are doing hot deployments. So, if I hot deploy, and one of my threads was busy using Class1, and then the new deployment starts a thread that uses Class1, and then the original thread finishes. Will the reference that the original thread held to Class1 be cleaned by GC, or is that a leak scenario?

Comment: Eventually if the thread stops the GC at some point will come in an GC the classloader including that class.  But keep in mind, the new deployment will be under its own classloader and have a different instance of Class1.class, so any reference to the old Class1 will not be accessible by the new deployment.  That being said, the strong reference to the new thread will only be on the new classloader not the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Note, in general, this is a bad design.  I could easily make your webserver fall over by executing a bunch of get calls (until you have so many running threads that the app falls over).  you should *always* be using a thread pool in a situation like this.

if you set this up to use a thread pool, and you manage the threadpool based on the lifecycle of the webapp, then you shouldn't have any issues (e.g. when the webapp gets re(un)deployed, the relevant thread pool should get shutdown).

on the other hand (ignoring issues with too many threads), if you want the thread to live beyond the lifetime of the webapp, then you should clear out the context classloader, because presumably this thread is not really related to the webapp in question anyway (since it has a different lifecycle).

finally, to answer one of your questions dsirectly, the implication of clearing out the context classloader is that the running thread may not have access to all the classes which are deployed for the webapp which launched it.

Comment: Agreed. In our case, however, the URL is both not public and throttled, so we don't need to worry about webserver failing due to too many requests. In essence, we need to very quickly return a response to the caller, and then do a finite amount of processing. As such, and as you mention, clearing the context classloader should be sufficient. Thank you.   ...  Oh, and yes, the processing should live beyond the life of the webapp if necessary (ie. for hot (re)deployments).